# Websocket - WSS not working on HTTPS in video recording

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, wss

Application + Implementation overview

In out application we need to performig video recording. We went ahead with MediaRecorder API hosted at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API.

We are getUserMedia API to access webCam and mic.
We are using  MediaRecorder API to record short blobs and sending it on application server hosting NodeJS WebSocket. ( Data transmission in short blobs to server is happening in every 2 second.

On app server we keep on accumulating data and finally create a .webm media file.

Issue:
All this is working fine with HTTP protocol, but whenever we put application on SSL and starts erring with below description;

Error Text: "WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:9000/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled"

Error screenshot: http://s33.postimg.org/9xasw0qa7/web_Socket_SSLIssue.jpg

Can any of you guide us with whats the issue specifically with HTTPS here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers will reject self-signed certificates for WebSocket connections as they consider them as unsafe. You can make a valid free certificate using [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) but you need frist edit and add face domain to hosts file.

If you use Windows press win key and past
notepad %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
and right click use Run as Administator and add fake domain and save

Now you need to set new SSL with nodejs with new certification for more detail.
https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener

For testing you use a fake domain instead of localhost etc. wss://fakedomain.com:9000